# Dynamically add image to powerpoint openxml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

I am creating power point 2007 files using the openxml.  I am able to add slides, shapes, text and manipulate them to create custom reports.  However, I can not find an example on how to dynamically load an image into my power points.  In principle I imagine that it would involve adding the image as a resource and then adding a reference to that resource.  Any example code would be great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will first need to add an ImagePart to your SlidePart like this:

```
ImagePart imagePart = slidePart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, "rId3");
```

The `"rId3"` needs to be the relationshipId that corresponds to your image that you are adding to the presentation.  You could also leave that parameter blank and a default relationship id will be created for you. Next you need to feed that image part the actual image:

```
imagePart.FeedData(new MemoryStream(photo.ToArray()));
```

If you are still having trouble take a look at these two blog posts.  They both show some code mid way down about adding photos to a presentation.

[Creating a report presentation based on data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/18/creating-a-presentation-report-based-on-data.aspx)

[Adding repeating data to PowerPoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/08/13/adding-repeating-data-to-powerpoint.aspx)